# How to add some symbol to every word in string?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am looking for fast and good way to add "-" before every word in string. For example "bla bla bla" should become "-bla -bla -bla".
I don't want to make an array of this string, then map it, etc. It looks like a wrong and slow way.
Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: How do you define word? Is `"42"` a word? What about `"___"`? What about `"-"`?

Comment: Does it matter if it's slow?  How much will that really cost you?  Getting a working (if inelegant) solution in place is probably a better use of your time than seeking premature optimization.

Comment: by 'making an array of the string' are you referring to the php split() function? That's the way I would approach this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we assume that a word is always separated by a whitespace and that the whitespace have no other special meaning we can do:

```
$str = 'bla bla bla';
$symbol = '-';

$newString = $symbol . str_replace(' ', " $symbol", $str);
echo $newString;
```

Output:

```
-bla -bla -bla
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice and easy solution.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the regular expressions:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '-$1', 'bla bla bla');
```

Search online for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions for more details!

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
preg_replace('/(\w+)/i', '-$1', $string);
```

Comment: No need to use the `i` modifier since `\w` already takes care of that